# Using something like user control to put in the <head> of aspx pages

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, include

Basically I just want something like an include control that I can put into the head and also something that could be nested(optional). I want to put the links to the css and js files in there so I have them all in one place. NO MASTERPAGES - I am trying to(read have to) avoid them for this project.  User controls work fine for this but I guess it is a weird way to use them and Visual studio does not render them properly in the HEAD section of the page within the editor. That being said I have successfully used user controls for that purpose with no problems. However, I wanted to check with .NET pros here and see if there is something else that would work better.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a [`Placeholder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder(VS.71).aspx) control to the head of your aspx file.  A `Placeholder` does not render any html itself but it does have a `ControlCollection` to which you can add whatever you like.

Comment: +1, but you have to understand there are issues with doing this (see http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/27/controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-issue-with-asp.net-mvc-rc1.aspx)

Comment: Nice find - I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [simulated include file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479009.aspx).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Is this comment critical for a 3 year old answer?

Comment: @Diodeus The site recently flagged a ton of older posts as low-quality, so they're getting reviewed.  The age of the post does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a literal control as well.